# Using Image Content Objects from tt_content in Extbase

Tags: typo3, extbase

I want to write an Extbase Backend module which needs a list of all Objects generated from tt_content with CType = 'image'.

Now I started defining a simple model

```
class Tx_Myextension_Domain_Model_Content extends Tx_Extbase_DomainObject_AbstractEntity
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $header;

    /**
     * @return the $header
     */
    public function getHeader()
    {
        return $this->header;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $header
     */
    public function setHeader($header)
    {
        $this->header = $header;
    }

}
```

and a Repository

```
class Tx_Myextension_Domain_Repository_ContentRepository extends Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Repository
{

    public function initializeObject()
    {
        $querySettings = $this->objectManager->create('Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Typo3QuerySettings');
        $querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
        $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
    }
}
```

As far as I know the initializeObject method is a way to get all content elements, no matter  which pid they have.

At last I tried to map my Content Class on tt_content:

```
plugin.tx_myextension {
  persistence {
    classes {
      Tx_Myextension_Domain_Model_Content {
        mapping {
          tableName = tt_content
          recordType = Tx_Myextension_Domain_Model_Content
          columns {
            header.mapOnProperty = header
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

module.tx_myextension {
    persistence < plugin.tx_myextension.persistence
}
```

No I want to use the Repo. e.g. countAll. Unfortunately it always returns 0. Looking for the MySQL query discovers the problem:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM tt_content  
WHERE (tt_content.CType='Tx_Myextension_Domain_Model_Content') 
  AND tt_content.deleted=0 AND tt_content.hidden=0 
  AND (tt_content.starttime<=1313073660) 
  AND (tt_content.endtime=0 OR tt_content.endtime>1313073660) 
  AND tt_content.sys_language_uid IN (0,-1) 
  AND tt_content.pid IN (0)
```

Typo 3 or Extbase or something different added all these where clauses to the query. I just want to get rid of the CType and pid clauses. As I said, I thought that the method used in the Repo leads to ignoring the pid, which is obviously not the case.

Can somebody help me? All I want is an array of Image Content Elements. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer: You'll most likely want to call

```
query->getQuerySettings()
    ->setRespectEnableFields(FALSE)
    ->setRespectSysLanguage(FALSE);
```

for your query. You can disable it for all queries in your repository's `initializeObject` method:

```
$querySettings = $this->objectManager->create('Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Typo3QuerySettings');
$querySettings
    ->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE)
    ->setRespectEnableFields(FALSE)
    ->setRespectSysLanguage(FALSE);
$this->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
```

See: [TYPO 3 API docs](http://typo3.org/api/typo3/class_tx___extbase___persistence___typo3_query_settings.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the Node "recordType" from your Persistence Definition.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I already tried it, but it didn't work either. I fixed this problem by reading the images from the database directly...